# javascript click(function) change color button

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tests').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#FFBF38');
    });
});
```

This code works ok, but when I click other button (.tests), I want to back to color was previously.
how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tests').click(function() {
        $(".tests").css('background-color', "YOUR PREVIOUS COLOR");
        $(this).css('background-color', '#FFBF38');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
 $('.tests').click(function() {
       $('.tests').css('background-color', 'your_old_color'); 
       $(this).css('background-color', '#FFBF38');
});
```

Comment: I cleaned up your formatting, but you've got some errors in there still.

Answer (score 0):

```
var startColor = "yourStartColor";

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.tests').click(function()
   {
   if($(this).css('background-color') == "#FFBF38")
      $(this).css('background-color', startColor);
   else
      $(this).css('background-color', "#FFBF38");
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer for the OP?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `toggleClass("");`
**HTML**

```
<div class="place"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.place { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: #336699; 
}
.green{
    background-color: black;
}
```

**Script**

```
$(".place").click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("green");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y5qdbf43/)**